# How to increment data from multiple forms Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I have many input forms for each data and I want to add `quantity` for each data

[input form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XWz9.png)

my input form

```
@foreach ($stocks as $stock)
    <div class="row mb-1">
        <div class="col col-lg-3 col-md-1">
            <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{ $stock->product_id }}">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sku[]" value="{{ $stock->sku }}" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-lg-2 col-md-1">
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="color_id[]" value="{{ $stock->color_id }}">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $stock->color->name }}" readonly>

        </div>
        <div class="col col-lg-2 col-md-1">
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="size_id[]" value="{{ $stock->size_id }}">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $stock->size->size }}" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-lg-2 col-md-1">
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="outlet_id[]" value="{{ $stock->outlet_id }}">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $stock->outlet->name }}" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-lg-2 col-md-1">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="stock[]" value="{{ old('stock') }}">
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

in controller

```
$where = [
    'product_id' => $request->product_id,
    'size_id' => $request->size_id,
    'color_id' => $request->color_id,
    'outlet_id' => $request->outlet_id
];

$stock = $request->all();
foreach($stock['stock'] as $item){
    Stock::query()->where($where)->increment('stock', $item);
}
```

How do I increment a `stock` column based on the SKU sent during input?

Comment: You may need to alter `name="product_id"` to `name="product_id[]"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increment the stock column based on the SKU sent during input, you should modify your loop to retrieve the SKU for each iteration and then use it in the `where` condition.

I assumes that the SKU is unique and can be used as a condition to identify the specific stock item you want to update. The loop iterates through each SKU, retrieves the corresponding product, size, color, and outlet information, and then increments the stock column accordingly. Adjust the code as needed based on your specific database structure and requirements.

```
    $stocks = $request->all();

foreach ($stocks['sku'] as $key => $sku) {
    // Check if the required keys exist
    if (isset($stocks['product_id'][$key], $stocks['size_id'][$key], $stocks['color_id'][$key], $stocks['outlet_id'][$key])) {
        $where = [
            'product_id' => $stocks['product_id'][$key],
            'size_id' => $stocks['size_id'][$key],
            'color_id' => $stocks['color_id'][$key],
            'outlet_id' => $stocks['outlet_id'][$key],
            'sku' => $sku,
        ];

        // Check if 'stock' key exists and is numeric
        if (isset($stocks['stock'][$key]) && is_numeric($stocks['stock'][$key])) {
            $stockQuantity = $stocks['stock'][$key];

            Stock::query()->where($where)->increment('stock', $stockQuantity);
        } else {
            // Handle the case where 'stock' is not set or is not numeric
            // You may log an error, throw an exception, or handle it accordingly.
        }
    } else {
        // Handle the case where one of the required keys is not set
        // You may log an error, throw an exception, or handle it accordingly.
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error `Uninitialized string offset 1` in `'product_id' => $stocks['product_id'][$key],`

Comment: i also get an error `Non-numeric value passed to increment method.`

Comment: Check The Edited Code. It will work, or give you the error to handle the issue. Also If you can share your migration file to see the data types, it might be the issue.